# Como mostrar dados de um db em 3 fragments tabbed?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como mostrar os dados obtidos de um banco de dados em uma tab com 3 fragments. Eu já consigo obter os dados na activity que está a tab. Minha dificuldade está em jogar esses dados em controles que estão dispostos nos 3 fragment.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Frag1 f1= new Frag1();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", "Marcelo");
            f1.setArguments(bundle);


        }
    });



}



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position){

            case 0:
                fragment=  new Frag1();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment= new Frag2();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment= new Frag3();
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
public TextView t1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
    t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtFinal1);


    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();



    if (bundle != null)
    {

        String link = bundle.getString("name");
        t1.setText(link);

    }
    else{Log.d("TagStart","Nulo");}

}
```

O button da activity envia os dados para mostrar no TextView do fragment mas nada acontece. Nemhum erro acontece também.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Pedro Gaspar. Sou novato por aqui Já postei com o trecho do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolvido**. Neste exemplo eu pego os dados de um DB do Azure e distribuo em 2 fragments tabbed. Um com os dados pessoais e no outro com enderço.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private MobileServiceTable<cadastroTable> mCadastroTable;
private CadastroTableAdapter mCadastroAdapter;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private String codigo,nome,endereco,bairro,cidade,estado;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
public  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_people);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_main);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    try {

        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "https://contaazure.azurewebsites.net",
                this));


        mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
            @Override
            public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                return client;
            }
        });


        mCadastroTable = mClient.getTable(cadastroTable.class);



        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
    }


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}




public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment=null;


        switch (position){

            case 0:
                fragment=  new PessoalFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("nome",nome);
                bundle.putString("codigo",codigo);

                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                break;

            case 1:
                fragment= new LocalizacaoFragment();
                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                bundle1.putString("endereco",endereco);
                bundle1.putString("bairro",bairro);
                bundle1.putString("cidade",cidade);
                bundle1.putString("estado",estado);

                fragment.setArguments(bundle1);

                break;


        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 2;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}





public  void refreshCadastroTable() {

      /// Aqui eu pego no DB do Azure os campos que serão que vão nas
      /// variáveis do bundle

}




private void createAndShowDialogFromTask(final Exception exception, String title) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
        }
    });
}


private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {
    Throwable ex = exception;
    if(exception.getCause() != null){
        ex = exception.getCause();
    }
    createAndShowDialog(ex.getMessage(), title);
}




private void createAndShowDialog(final String message, final String title) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Nos fragments

**PessoalFragment**

```
public class PessoalFragment extends Fragment  {

private EditText edt_cdigo, edt_nome;
public  String _codigo, _nome, ;
public Bundle bundle;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pessoal, container, false);

     edt_codigo = (EdiText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.codigo);
     edt_nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nome);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    bundle= getArguments();

    _codigo = bundle.getString("codigo");
    _nome = bundle.getString("nome");


}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



    if (bundle != null) {

        edt_codigo.setText(_codigo);
        edt_nome.setText(_nome);

    }


}
```

**LocalizacaoFragment**

```
public class LocalizacaoFragment extends Fragment  {

private EditText edt_endereco, edt_bairro, edt_cidade, edt_estado;
public  String _endereco, _bairro, _cidade, _estado ;
public Bundle bundle;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_localizacao, container, false);

     edt_endereco = (EdiText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.endereco);
     edt_bairro = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bairro);
     edt_cidade = (EdiText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cidade);
     edt_estado = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.estado);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    bundle= getArguments();

    _endereco = bundle.getString("endereco");
    _bairro = bundle.getString("bairro");
    _cidade = bundle.getString("cidade");
    _estado = bundle.getString("estado");


}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



    if (bundle != null) {

        edt_endereco.setText(_endereco);
        edt_bairro.setText(_bairro);
        edt_cidade.setText(_cidade);
        edt_estado.setText(_estado);

    }


}
```

Obrigado Lucas Pugliese pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Oh SectionsPagerAdapter tem um `Frag1`, mas em nenhum momento você atribui o Bundle a ele. Você na verdade está criando um `Frag1` novo dentro do **OnClick** do botão.

Uma outra coisa que você tem que observar é o ciclo de vida da activity e do fragment, porque o clique do botão está acontecendo depois do **onActivityCreated** e nesse momento o **Bundle** sempre será null

[image: Ciclo de vida da activity e fragment]

Nesse seu caso em específico eu acredito que a melhor abordagem seria você criar um método `SetText()` no seu **Fragment**, criar um `GetFragment()` dentro do adapter para acessar o mesmo da **Activity** e simplesmente chamar o `SetText()` dentro do `OnClick`.

Comment: Obrigado!!! Era isso mesmo. **Oh SectionsPagerAdapter tem um Frag1, mas em nenhum momento você atribui o Bundle a ele**. Erro de iniciante como eu.

Comment: Posta como ficou o resultado final e vota na resposta. Obrigado por dar retorno ^^